# Average of number of rows in a custom object with reference to Another custom object field

Tags: custom-object, lookup, dashboard

I created two custom objects (Orders & Order Items)

Orders - List of Orders with Total Price and Other details

Order Items - List of Items in an Order with reference to the Order Id in Orders Object (lookup)

How can i get/ In which way to proceed to get the average items per order in a custom report, 
I check 'add formula' in reports but it is not useful for this purpose